# Uploading an image with jsp Servlet, "parseRequest" Error

Tags: file, jsp, servlets, upload

I m pretty new in java, and understand its concept. I followed a tutorial on how to upload an image with jsp servlet, But I am getting an error on the "parseRequest"

List items = upload.**parseRequest**(request);

Here is my code :

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();

    if(!ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)) {
        out.print("Nothing to upload");
        return;
    }
    FileItemFactory itemFactory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
    ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(itemFactory);
    try {
        List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(request);
        for(FileItem item:items) {
            String contentType = item.getContentType();
            if(!contentType.equals("image.png")) {
                out.print("Only PNG format are accepted.");
                continue;
            }
            File uploadDir = new File("My directory will be here !!!");
            File file  = File.createTempFile("img",".png",uploadDir);
            item.write(file);
            out.print("File Saved Successfully!!");
        }

    }catch(FileUploadException e) {
        out.print("Failed to upload the file!!!");
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        out.print("Can't save the file!!!");
    }
}
```

it is supposed to upload the image, but i m getting that error 

Geting an error : HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error

Comment: can you show us the error?

Comment: I figured it out! thank you